# How to catch psycopg2.DataError and psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat without collision

Tags: python, postgresql, error-handling, try-catch, psycopg2

I have an script to copy csv to my database in postgresql. The csv comes from different sources, so I have to manage different errors regarding to the format of csv.
The essentially the basic block of code is something like that

```
import psycopg2
...

connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)

try:
        file_object = open(cleaned_file)
        cur = connection.cursor()

        copy_sql = """
            COPY %s"""+headers_tostring + """FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
            DELIMITER as E'""" + delimiter + "'"
        copy_sql = (copy_sql + " QUOTE E'" + quote + "'") if quote != '' else copy_sql
        copy_sql = copy_sql + " NULL AS ''" 

        cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % schema_table, file=file_object)
        connection.commit()
        cur.close()
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as e:
        print ('psycopg2.ProgrammingError')
        print(("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]))
        #do something 
        connection.rollback()

    except psycopg2.DataError as e:
        print ('psycopg2.DataError')
        print (e)
        print(("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]))
        #do something 
        connection.rollback()

    except psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat as e:
        print ('psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat')
        print (e)
        print(("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]))
        #do something 
        connection.rollback()




    finally:
        connection.close()
```

My main issue was that when I got an error of type `psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat` this error is catching like `psycopg2.DataError`.
I assumed that `psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat` is subclass of `psycopg2.DataError` and for this reason that happened. 
Checking the documentation i got that `BadCopyFileFormat` is a SQLSTATE exception classes and the base class is `DataError`, and that could explain that.

I solve my issue now changing the order of the block exception I put before `psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat`  and after psycopg2.DataError

```
 except psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat as e:
        print ('psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat')
        print (e)
        print(("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]))
        #do something 
        connection.rollback()
   except psycopg2.DataError as e:
        print ('psycopg2.DataError')
        print (e)
        print(("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]))
        #do something 
        connection.rollback()
```

By now that solve my current problem, but I'm not sure if this is the best option or I can get another problem with other inputs.

Is this the best way to manage this exceptions?